# GeneralPath not drawing with changed scale

Tags: java, graphics, scale, draw, shapes

Im currently making a sidescroller game which uses randomly generated terrain that scrolls in the background.  The terrain is basically an instance of the GeneralPath class.  When the terrain generates, the corners (0, 0) and (width, 0) are included in the path since the height of the viewing canvas isnt known yet.  To make the terrain appear right-side-up, i added the following lines of code:

```
g.translate(0, getHeight());
g.scale(0, -1);
```

This should flip the coordinate system into Cartesian format with the bottom left being 0, 0.
For some reason, the terrain isnt drawing.  When i comment-out these lines, it works, but is upside-down.  If i only comment out the scale command and change the amount translated by to a smaller number, it also draws successfully (upside-down and translated a small amount).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

As you noticed, you need to scale the x axis as well - g.scale(1, -1);

Comment: Im drawing the terrain at 0, 0, it covers the whole screen.  When i flip it (-1) it would be drawn right-side up, but above the actual screen.  The goal is to draw the image, flipped right side up, in reference to the bottom left instead of the top left

Comment: additionally, if the only transform i do is scale(0, .5) it should draw it at half scale, it doesnt

Comment: What if you do g.scale(0, -1); g.translate(0, -getHeight())?

Comment: i feel like an idiot.... the x should have a scale of 1 not 0, sorry for the inconvenience